# Java Applet does not display on HTML page

Tags: java, html

My Java applet (called NameInLights.class) does not display when I load my HTML page. The .class file definitely exists, and the other parts of my HTML display in their correct places on the page. Java is enabled in my browser and the applet works fine in the AppletViewer.

Here is my java code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class NameInLights extends Applet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Random r = new Random();
    String name = "Imulsion";//must keep my real name secret! :)
    public void init(){
        setSize(500,500);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(new Color(r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255)));
    g.setFont(new Font("Comic sans ms",Font.BOLD,55));  
    g.drawString(name,125,250);
    for(int loop=0;loop<500;loop++)
    {
        int red = r.nextInt(255);
        int green = r.nextInt(255);
        int blue = r.nextInt(255);
        int x = r.nextInt(500);
        int y = r.nextInt(500);
        g.setColor(new Color(red,green,blue));
        g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,24));
        g.drawString("*",x,y);
    }
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
    <p>
     Here comes an awesome applet!
    </p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <applet code="NameInLights.class" width = 500 height = 500>
    </applet>
    <button type = "button" onclick = "window.location.reload()">
     Change applet colours
    </button>
 <body>
<html>
```

Why does it not display?

Comment: Google chrome. It asks me if I should allow java to work on the page, obviously i click yes. I tried on internet explorer that didnt work either

Comment: Have you tried clearing browser and Java cache?

Comment: Check the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) for output.  And better to add 50 as a bounty, than post duplicate questions.

Comment: If I did, I would lose 50 rep and then only have 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, google Chrome officially does not support deprecated tag `applet`. 
Use tag `object` instead.

Comment: So what would my object tag look like?

Comment: I just tested Google Chrome (version 21.0.1180.60 m) using a plain applet element in simple HTML and it works just fine.  Perhaps you mean that Chrome does not ship with the JRE?  That makes perfect sense.  A browser should not ship with every conceivable plug-in, instead users should install them as per need (prompted by HTML).

Answer (score 0):

As a first look, you can use:

```
appletviewer your_html_file.html
```

Then, you probably need to download a plugin for your browser:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141438.html
```

Comment: <html>
<body>
<h1>heres a cool applet</h1>
<hr />
<object codetype="application/java" classid = "java:NameInLights.class" width = "500" height = "500">
</object>
</body>
</html>